# Is there a dictionary of dictionaries in QTP version of VBS?

Tags: dictionary, vbscript, qtp

Something similar to `Set<String, Set<String>>` in Java?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Set is an unordered collection of unique elements. Many Set implementations are based on hash tables (possibly of key-value pairs). VBScript has a Dictionary class -

```
Dim dicParent : Set dicParent = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

You can't add the same key twice, so the keys of a VBScript Dictionary represent/model a Set (the Set is ordered (by insertion), however). Nothing keeps you from putting (other) Dictionaries into the values:

```
>> Dim dicParent : Set dicParent = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>> dicParent.Add "Fst", CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>> dicParent("Fst").Add "Snd", "child of parent"
>> WScript.Echo dicParent("Fst")("Snd")
>>
child of parent
```

In VBScript (and **theory**), you can even use objects as keys (not only strings as in other languages):

```
>> Dim dicParent : Set dicParent = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>> Dim dicChild  : Set dicChild  = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>> dicParent(dicChild) = "child of parent"
>> WScript.Echo dicParent(dicChild)
>>
child of parent
```

Your **practical** mileage may vary.

Comment: Nice remark about using objects as keys. Allthough, I'll have to think about a practical use for that. Maybe a poor man's linked list, stack or queue.

Comment: Oh, I've used it to implement something like API caching -- to minimize references to the DataTable object, storing object properties (or references) in a dictionary. Works fine, can be useful indeed.